# Extract (demux) subtitles using avcodec_decode_subtitle2 (FFmpeg)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, ifstream, subtitle

I found some code, edited it a little bit to print text of subtitles, but I'm not sure how to save subtitles to file (extract from video file, e.g. mkv)

next code just prints a lot of lines, not all of them contains subtitle text

```
std::ofstream out ("/path/to/extracted/subtitles.srt");

while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &pkt) == 0) {
    int got_frame = 0;
    int ret = avcodec_decode_subtitle2(aCodecCtx, subtitle, &got_frame, &pkt);
    if (ret >= 0 && got_frame) {
        AVSubtitleRect **rects = subtitle->rects;
        for (i = 0; i < subtitle->num_rects; i++) {
            AVSubtitleRect rect = *rects[i];
            if (rect.type == SUBTITLE_ASS) {
                printf("ASS %s", rect.ass);
            } else if (rect.x == SUBTITLE_TEXT) {;
                printf("TEXT %s", rect.text);
            }
        }
        // it just writes some big file (similar to videofile size)
        //out.write((char*)pkt.data, pkt.size);
    }
}
out.close();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking "rect.x" against SUBTITLE_TEXT, when that should be "rect.type", as in the conditional above it.